# Return to filtered listview in JQuerymobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using listview to filter a large number of items. Each item is a link to another page which I use to edit details for the selected item. How can I return to my listview and have it remember the filter text I had previously typed?

Answer (score 0):

You should send the filter data to your backend framework as a url query string, and let it handle the data and request redirects. For eg:

- When someone clicks on a link, send to url such as www.example.com/page.html?filter1=xyz&filter2=abc
- Use the filter to create the form submission data, or however you want it to persist. You might want to use signals or post query with included filter data.